# SQL Server 2008 Management Studio Not Showing Database

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2008-r2, ssms

I've got a fresh install of Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 and just installed SQL Server 2008 R2, including SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio.

When I go into Management Studio, it does NOT show the SQL Server instance that was created during setup. It only has (local) and won't let me connect to it at all.

Any ideas?

Comment: what doe sthe sql server configuration manager have under "sql server services"

Comment: I got it. The instance name was correct, I just wasn't providing enough information in the server field. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Management studio requires `<computer name>/<instance name>` under the "Server" section. I was only entering in the instance name.

Comment: Thanks! Anyway it is <computer name>\<instance name> (at least on Win7 and SQL Server 2008R2).

Comment: this failed for me. see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First check if SQL Server 2008 instance is installed show on your SQL Configuration Manager.

If it doesn't exist you need to re install you sql server 2008 r2 and follow these steps on this link below:

[SQL SERVER – 2008 – Step By Step Installation Guide With Images](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/12/sql-server-2008-step-by-step-installation-guide-with-images/)

And it exist just add server name : yourpcname

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked for me:

enter "localhost" as the server (computer-name\MSSQLSERVER failed)

Not sure why but the name "MSSQLSERVER" as shown in Configuration Manager is not the name shown when I log in via Management Studio.  The name in Management Studio is SQL Server 9.0.5000 which corresponds to SQL Server 2005 SP4 (which is correct in my case).